# system monitor file systems strange behaviour

Tags: filesystem, system-monitor

when I open the system monitor app a strange thing happens. The folder /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell 20 GB is a bit strange I do not understand what this
folder is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaDHH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a fan of snaps.

However, that directory on my system contains the dictionaries. But 20GB? How many dictionaries are you downloading?  On my system its just EN_GB and EN_US.And that takes about 5MB, no where near 20GB.

You can check by going to Firefox -> Menu (the three horizontal bars on the right hand side of the address bar) -> Settings and then, in the General section, look at the languages. If you have many more than you need, remove them.

Do an ls -lh on the directory and see what it lists.

Comment: It seems like a bug on my computer, I agree that the dictionary is not  20 GB but the system monitor display  20 GB .very very strange